# How to select all categories and count number of each category articles in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, categories

Category table:

```
id, name
---------
1   cat1
2   cat2
3   cat3 
4   cat4
```

Article table:

```
id, cid, title
--------------
1   1    title1
2   3    title2
3   1    title3
4   2    title4
```

How to select  all categories and count number of each category articles  in MySQL? I need a mysql query that will select all category and total count of articles belonging to each category  and order by category id.

Expected output table:

```
+-------+-------+    
|  name | count |    
+-------+-------+    
|  cat1 |     2 |    
|  cat2 |     1 |    
|  cat3 |     1 |  
|  cat4 |     0 |  
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Already tried something? Searched for answer? Hey, it is for 2 minutes googling....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use subquery like

```
SELECT c.name,(select count(*) from article where cid = c.id) as count  FROM cat c WHERE 1 GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: why DV for this answer ?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    c.`name`,
    COUNT(a.cid) AS `count`
FROM
    categories c
    LEFT JOIN article a ON c.id = a.cid
GROUP BY
    c.`name`
ORDER BY
    c.`name`
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
SELECT c.`name`, count(a.cid) as count FROM category
LEFT JOIN article
ON c.id = a.cid
GROUP BY a.cid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.name,count(b.title)count from category a, article b where c.id = a.cid group by c.name order by a.cid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work. Please check.

```
select
    Category.name.
    ifnull(count(Article.cid),0) as count
FROM
    Category
LEFT JOIN
    Article 
on
    Article.cid=Category.id
group by
    Category.Id
```